# I'm trying to make 2 h1 tags not overlap eachother but have different heights on the same line

Tags: html, css

As i've already stated in the title i'm trying to put two h1 tags on the same line, near eachother but have different heights.
Basically i'm trying to do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLlT6.jpg

But so far i've been unsuccesful

For now I've been able to put it where i want it, but it overlaps, so that's a problem.

I honestly don't know what to do anymore.

```
<html>
   <head>  <title> Esercizio </title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <style type=text/css>

      body{        }

      p    { letter-spacing: 0.1em;
               word-spacing: 2mm;
           }

      i    {       }

      h1{ background-color: #EAEAEA;
          height: 68px;    width:90%;
          padding-left: 3mm;
      text-align: center;
    }


      h1.down { position: absolute;
           top: 5px;  left:100px;
           height: 50px;
           background-color: #EEE; padding-left: 0.5mm;
     text-align: center;
     z-index:2;

       }


   div{width:50%; text-align: right; font-size: 125%;
       background-color: #EE5; padding-right: 0.1mm;
       border-right: dotted 1mm  red;
       border-bottom: dashed 3px  blue;
       border-top; border-left: none;
       float : right;
           }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>   Parlando <h1 class=down>Sparlando</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to be mean, but there are a few errors in your code in general that you might want to double check.

That said, if we give the segment we wish to move down a span rather that a new h1 altogether, we can manipulate it a lot more easily, and cleanly. Giving that span a relative position rather than the absolute position you gave it, lets us move it about relative to its container.

Final thing, I've changed your height to line-height to center the text a bit better, thought I'd look at perhaps some flexbox properties to have it centered perfectly.

A slightly more elegant solution may well be move the span down 3px and the left segment of your text up 3px so they are both symmetrical and centered.

Hope this helps.

```html
<html>
   <head>  <title> Esercizio </title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <style type=text/css>

      body{        }

      p    { letter-spacing: 0.1em;
               word-spacing: 2mm;
           }

      i    {       }

      h1{ background-color: #EAEAEA;
          line-height: 68px;    width:90%;
          padding-left: 3mm;
          text-align: center;
    }


      .down { position: relative;
           top: 15px;  
           height: 50px;
           background-color: #EEE; padding-left: 0.5mm;
     text-align: center;
     z-index:2;

       }


   div{width:50%; text-align: right; font-size: 125%;
       background-color: #EE5; padding-right: 0.1mm;
       border-right: dotted 1mm  red;
       border-bottom: dashed 3px  blue;
       border-top; border-left: none;
       float : right;
           }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>   Parlando <span class=down>Sparlando</span></h1>
```

Comment: This helped me immensely, though it worries me that you found some problems, because this code was copy and pasted from my professor's demo.